# Passing hidden object from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller sending a view model consisting of a list and an object client to a view.
The view will show the list in a grid but hide the object client.
Here is the view:

```
@model .Business.BusinessModels.MatchesClientViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SaveClient";
}

<h2>SaveClient</h2>

<h3>
    The info captured matches @Model.ClientMatches.Count()
</h3>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveClient", "Client", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model.ClientMatches);
        @grid.GetHtml(columns: new[]

                             {
                        grid.Column("Name"),
                        grid.Column("Surname"),
                        grid.Column("Email"),
                    })

        @Html.Hidden("client", Model.client)

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
            </div>
     }
```

My action which submit button hits is:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SaveClient(MatchesClientViewModel matchesClientViewModel)
{
    *some actions*
    return View();
}
```

However the view model sent to controller from view is null.  Any idea how to properly pass the hidden part of the view model to the controller?

Comment: The Model.Client is an object? Or is it just an id?

Comment: @AnastasiosSelmanis : It is an object

Comment: Then I'm afradid you will have to pass every field of the object like this:         @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.client.Id, Model.client.Id),         @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.client.someattribute., Model.client.someattribute) etc. And it will map on your form submit. Generally it would better to use just client.id since probably that is what you will want on the backend or if you want the object just get the client object again from the backend.

Comment: Then I will have to change my action, SaveClient, parameter as well?  Instead of using MatchesClientViewModel as parameter, I use someattribute type?

Comment: @tabby, nope, the model binder should be able to figure out that these fields belong to the `client` field of the model, and create it from property values for you. However this is only true if the field is strongly typed. Just `object` most likely won't work

Comment: I wrote as an answer some possible ways to do your job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass an entire object as hidden you will have to add hidden fields for every attribute of the class like this:

Let's say the model Client is  something like this

```
public class Client
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeAttribute { get; set; }
    \\ ......
}
```

In order to pass your values to your Action you should add to your form every property as a hidden field like this

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.client.Id, Model.client.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.client.Someattribute, Model.client.Someattribute)
```

One other way to go would be to change your model to something like this:

```
public class MatchesClientViewModel
{
    public List<ClientMatch> ClientMatches { get; set; }
    public string clientId { get; set; }
    \\ .....
}
```

and pass your clientId only to your view and back to the controller like this

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.clientId., Model.clientId)
```

Or If you do not want to change your ViewModel just add a hidden field like you did for your object for the client id and pass it as an extra parameter to the controller

```
@Html.HiddenFor('clientId', Model.client.Id)
```

and make your action like this

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SaveClient(MatchesClientViewModel matchesClientViewModel, string clientId)
{
    *some actions*
    return View();
}
```

Comment: It's best to only post the client ID and retrieve the object server side from a cache or a database (and check the logged in user has indeed access to this client ID). Don't naively trust what was submitted in the form, even if it comes from hidden input. You may also want to take a look at anti-forgery tokens: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/

Comment: @AlexSanséau in my comments to the question I mentioned that the best thing he could do is what you mention. Not for authentication purposes but mostly for a good practise. I just posted an answer that includes a way to do what he asked.